# Control the color of a (link) button in CSS

Tags: html, css

If have a raspberry, which controls several electronic devices. I have also a webpage which shows the state of the devices 
There are 3 states a button can have  "In use" (orange) "Free" (green) "and Out" (red)

CSS

```
a:link {
    border:2px solid #456879;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:link.uit{
    background-color: green;    
    }
a:link.aan{
    background-color: orange;   
    }
a:link.noi{                         <!--- noi= device Not In Use  -->
    background-color: red;  
    }
```

Within my python webserver I create a page which contains the following parts
(python create these HTML depend on the state of the device 
HTML

```
<!---- when off
    <div>
       <a href="#" class="uit">Relax <br>Stopped: 15:22</a>
    </div>

<!---- when on
    <div>
       <a href="#" class="aan">Relax <br>Started: 15:22</a>
    </div>

<!--- when not in use 
    <div>
       <a href="#" class="noi">Relax <br>Out</a>
    </div>
```

The problem is that when I generate    Relax 
Out the color stays ORANGE, while I expect it would change to RED

Comment: Your code is all fine barring the invalid comment syntax within the `.noi` selector. Remove it and the code should work as you expect.

Comment: And which part isn't working - does the element have the appropriate class when you test it?

Comment: lol, you are right Harry, I used the wrong method  for commenting. Thank you, problem is solved

Comment: CSS uses `/*comment*/` for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the odd comment

```
<!--- noi= device Not In Use  -->
```

from the CSS code.

Comment: Are you serious? This was answered 22 min ago by Henry!

Comment: @Miro You mean Harry? I marked it as a CW, for completeness. SO shouldn't have such empty questions.